# Не работает UIBarButtonItem правильно , как правильно сделать?

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c

Хочу чтоб при нажатии на кнопку toSecond вылнялся переход, а обратно срабатывала кнопка backBtn2First, но ничего не срабатывает. То есть работает переход но никак не UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp , Такое ощущение что backBtn2First просто игнорируеться. Как сделать чтоб работало правильно?

```
   -(IBAction) backBtn2First //для обратного перехода
    {
        FirstViewController *fvc = [[FirstViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
        [UIView  beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:fvc animated:NO];
        [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }

    -(IBAction)toSecond
    {
    SecondViewController *svc = [[SecondViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"InfoViewController" bundle:nil];
     UIBarButtonItem *backBtn2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"try back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(backBtn2First)];   
    [[self navigationItem]setBackBarButtonItem:backBtn2];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: То, что я вижу в коде метода backBtn2First не ведет обратно по навигации, в создает новый экран и пушит его в стек экраном, что явно совсем не то, что хотелось, так?

Answer (score 1):

В методе backBtn2First замени весь код на:

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: YES];

Он вернет navigationController на предидущий контроллер. Также желательно перенести этот метод и создание кнопки backBtn2 в класс SecondViewController.